# xcode get the fontsize of a textview

Tags: xcode, textview, font-size

I want to increase the size of a textview when a button is pressed.

for that i need to know what the fontsize is. how do i know?

I would do it like that:

```
CGFloat *newsize =  (// here the fontsize + 1);
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:newsize];
```

Answer (score -1):

for(int i;i<[up to size];i++)
{

CGFloat *newsize = i;
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:i];

}